# How to parse json object in an array

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a json object like this

```
{
  "op": "create",
  "collection": "test",
  "args": [
    { "a": 1 },
    { "b": 2 },
    { "c": 3 }
  ]
}
```

I want to print out all the args element and then divide them seperately. This is what I did to parse json element, I was able to get "op" or "collection" element. However, I was not failed to get "args " element. Here is what I do with the code, what output it gave.

```
var config= JSON.parse(item) //  I am getting item from the command line
console.log ("op is"+ config.op);
console.log("arg is"+ config.args);
```

The output is; op is create
args is [object Object], [object Object] ,[object Object]

By the way, I also tried to use stringfy method and it did not work as well

Comment: Try `console.log("arg is", config.args);` instead, or `console.log("arg is", JSON.stringify(config.args));`

Comment: config.args is an array of objects, if you want to console.log those, you need to iterate through config.args one by one .. *`I also tried to use stringfy method and it did not work`* you did it wrong then

Comment: Or `console.log("arg is", [].concat(...config.args.map(Object.values)))`

Answer (score 1):

Your output `args is [object Object], [object Object] ,[object Object]` is merely an artifact of how you wrote the `console.log` command. You've used `+` to combine the string `"args is"` with `config.args`, so `config.args` is being converted to a string, and since it is an array, the resulting string is a comma-delimited series of each of its elements converted in turn to a string, and an object converted to a string becomes `"[object Object]"`.

Instead, print it this way:

```js
const config = {
  "op": "create",
  "collection": "test",
  "args": [
    { "a": 1 },
    { "b": 2 },
    { "c": 3 }
  ]
};

console.log("arg is", config.args);
```

> How to parse json object in an array

You're deeply confused about the meaning of the word JSON, how to use (or not use) the term "JSON object", and what "parse" means.

"JSON" means exactly one thing: a **string** following a particular syntax, representing some data. Such a string representation is used because it can be passed around between computer systems, such as clients and servers, and used in different languages. As the [json.org](http://json.org) site says (my emphasis):

> JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format. [...] It is **based on a subset of JavaScript** [...] JSON is a **text format** that is completely language independent

In other words, an object literal in JavaScript, such as `{a: 1}`, or the object which it defines, is **not** JSON, and will never be JSON, and it is incorrect to refer to it as JSON, or as a "JSON object"--a thing which doesn't even exist in the world, and could not, since JSON is a string. An object in JavaScript is called exactly one thing: a **JavaScript object**, or if the context is clear, just **object** (in case you were wondering, it is also never called a "hash", or a "dictionary", or an "associative array"). Such a JavaScript object may have been obtained from JSON retrieved from a server, or it may be destined to eventually be converted into JSON to be sent to a server, and it may even be stored in a variable named `jsonObj` to remind us of its origin or its destination, but that still does not make it JSON. It is a **JavaScript object**.

The term "parse" has a very specific meaning in computer science. It means to analyze some input, normally a string, according to some grammar or syntax, and to **convert** it into some kind of parsed representation. Wikipedia says:

> Parsing is the process of analyzing a string of symbols conforming to the rules of a formal grammar.

A JavaScript object does not ever need to be parsed. It is already in the form of a JavaScript object. You can access properties directly, with the basic syntax `object.property`, or `object["property"]`. Accessing properties like this is **not** parsing, and should never be called parsing.

Parsing is something that applies to JSON, when that term is used in the correct sense, namely the sense of a string. We parse the string, according to JSON syntax rules, to create a parsed representation, which in the case of JavaScript will be a JavaScript object. This is what `JSON.parse` does. And of course `JSON.stringify` goes in the opposite direction.

In the normal course of JavaScript programming, you will actually find relatively few cases where you need to worry about JSON, or parsing, or stringifying. If you do find yourself worrying about those things, it likely that you're misunderstanding something about your data or your tools. Most APIs for retrieving data from a server will automatically convert JSON provided by the server into a JavaScript object, giving you something that is already parsed and can be accessed directly. Most APIs for delivering data to a server will automatically convert the JavaScript object provided by you into JSON. In neither case do you typically have to worry about parsing or stringifying, other than perhaps making sure to specify some option such as `responseType: json` on the XHR object. You may need to worry about parsing and stringification if you are storing JavaScript objects in "local storage", since local storage by definition stores strings.

> I want to print out all the `args` element [sic] and then divide them seperately [sic]. This is what I did to parse json element, I was able to get `op` or `collection` element. However, I was not failed to get `args` element.

I understand not everyone is a native English speaker, but it is quite hard to understand this sentence. I guess you mean "print out all the elements (plural) of `args`". I don't know what you mean by "divide them separately". Do you mean to do something with the elements one by one?  I also don't know what you mean by "This is what I did to parse json element". This is a perfect example of the need to avoid using terms like "parse" and "json" incorrectly; you simply confuse yourself and everyone else.

If what you are saying is that you want to print out the elements of the `args` property one by one, the way to loop over elements of an array is covered in every basic JS tutorial and intro:

```js
const config = { args: [{ "a": 1 }, { "b": 2 }, { "c": 3 }] };
    
for (const elt of config.args) console.log(elt);
```

The [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) form, which you should definitely learn if you don't already know it, loops over the elements of an array.

Or, of course you could also use a regular `for` loop to loop over the **indices** of the array, from `0` up to `config.args.length`.

But what if you want to break down the `{"a": 1}` property by property, and print each property and its value, one by one? (Is this perhaps what you meant when you said "divide them separately"?) In that case, we need a way to find all the properties, assuming we do not know them in advance. Finding an object's properties will also be covered pretty early in any JS intro, so we don't really need to go into the details here, but let's try writing a function to print out all an object's properties and their values:

```
function printObjectPropertiesAndValues(object) {
}
```

We can use this in the code above as follows:

```
for (const elt of config.args) printObjectPropertiesAndValues(elt);
```

Since we are just calling a function now on each element, some people might prefer to use `map`:

```
config.args.map(printObjectPropertiesAndValues);
```

You should make very sure you understand what the above line does and how it works.

Anyway, how do we write `printObjectPropertiesAndValues`? There are a couple of approaches. There are some ideas in other answers. One would be to use the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement, which loops across some object's properties.

```
function printObjectPropertiesAndValues(object) {
  for (const prop in object) console.log("property", prop, "has value", obj[prop]);
}
```

You should also make sure you understand exactly what the above code does, and in particular what `obj[prop]` means and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

So the `config.args` is an array, so we loop throught the array (using `for(var x of config.args){`), to get the objects inside (E.g: `{ "a": 1 }`), then we get the value alone from the object by looping though the keys (using `for(var key in x)`), which in our case is only one and get the repective value `x[key]` and finally push it to the output array `output.push(x[key])`, then we show the results in the console!

```js
var jsonString = `{
  "op": "create",
  "collection": "test",
  "args": [
    { "a": 1 },
    { "b": 2 },
    { "c": 3 }
  ]
}`
var output = [];
var config= JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log ("op is"+ config.op);
console.log("keys:")
for(var x of config.args){
  for(var key in x){
    console.log(x[key]);
    output.push(x[key]);
  }
}
console.log("Final Array:")
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for command line:
1. set your json to a var like this `a={"op": "create","collection": "test","args": [{ "a": 1 },{ "b": 2 },{ "c": 3 }]}`
2. pipe to jq like this `echo "$a" | jq -r .args